# Scraping IMDb Review Page with lxml and requests package

Tags: python, lxml, lxml.html

I want to extract the user reviews of a  particular movie with help of lxml.
Before that, I need to find out the number of reviews first.

An example review page is [Interstellar](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0816692/reviews?start=0)

I found the XPath where User Reviews are found with the help of Firebug:

```
/html/body/div[1]/div/layer/div[4]/div[3]/div[3]/div[3]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]
```

I have this code to extract that line

```
reviewPage = lxml.html.document_fromstring(requests.get("http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0816692/reviews?start=0").content)
number_of_reviews = reviewPage.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/layer/div[4]/div[3]/div[3]/div[3]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]")[0]
```

However, on printing the number of reviews, I get nothing. What is the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following line to extract the number of reviews:

```
number_of_reviews = int(reviewPage.xpath("//div[@id = 'tn15content']/table[2]/tr/td[2]")[0].text_content().split()[0])
```

You can even use your own code if you modify it a little bit. The problem lies in your XPath. Get rid of the `tbody` part and it works.

```
number_of_reviews = reviewPage.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/layer/div[4]/div[3]/div[3]/div[3]/table[2]/tr/td[2]")[0]
```

You possibly got the structure of the HTML with the help of your browser's developer tools and this adds the `tbody` even though it does not exist in the html. If you watch the HTML file directly through `View Source (Ctrl+U)` you will realize that there is no `tbody` in the file.

See [Why does firebug add <tbody> to <table>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678494/why-does-firebug-add-tbody-to-table)

Comment: Why can't I access it using my xpath?

Comment: @GokuShanth Because in your XPath you explicitly search for the `tbody` element that does not exist in the HTML file, but your browser added it as an element, so you get no result with your original XPath because it does not match any existing tree. Remove the `tbody` and your XPath works

Comment: I was trying for this page also - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18366211/ssrs-look-up-field-in-dataset-that-is-not-part-of-report

And get the question title using xpath. The xpath is - 

    /html/body/div[5]/div[2]/div/div[1]/h1/a

But it still didn't give me the text. Why ???

Comment: @GokuShanth Thats the XPath if you are logged in. Your python script is not logged in to stackoverflow so you have to use a different one: `/html/body/div[5]/div[2]/div/div[2]/h1/a`. If you use the shorter and more meaningful XPath `"//div[@id='question-header']/h1/a"` it works for both cases

Comment: Thanks a million! I think Firebug is not that great. The XPath Finder on Chrome is better.